# telegram bot api - get all messages in a group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on **Telegram bot api** in my java application. I have created a **super group** and add my bot to this as an administrator. I want to get all messages in that super group(not deleted messages) via bot. Is there any useful method for doing that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. first, you should "disable" privacy of your bot so it can access to all messages in groups. second, use `getUpdates` to see recent updates and user messages will be there.

Comment: I tested this method. It returned all messages, event deleted messages. I don't want deleted messages.

Comment: Well, as far as i know telegram doesn't have this functionality. If you post a message as admin in your group and then you delete it, message will just disappear in group but it actually exist in api and telegram doesn't sent any additional data for deleted message.

Comment: {
      "update_id": 215861401,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 18,
        "from": {
          "id": 191322468,
          "first_name": "Vahid",
          "username": "Vahid_Mas"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": -1001096962216,
          "title": "as",
          "type": "supergroup"
        },
        "date": 1476682413,
        "text": "deleted post"
      }
    }

Comment: I have a supergroup which has been created about one month ago. Now I add my bot as an admin user. How can I get ALL messages from the begin to current. when I call Update method by 0 as the offset, I just get the message from the time of adding bot to group, and can not get previous messages. any idea?

Comment: @A.Dara you can spend hours to select messages with butches (50-100 messages if I remember correctly) and forward them to your bot. It will get all messages you have sent and use information (such as date) not current but from forwarded message. Is it clear?